# Laptop does not sleep when running battery powered (Dell Vostro 3590)

Tags: 20.04, power-management, budgie, standby

I've recently installed Ubuntu Budgie 20.04 LTS on my Dell Vostro 3590 which was shipped with Ubuntu GNOME. I've noticed that when the machine is running on battery, it does not sleep after 15 minutes which is my current settings. What could be the reason?

`systemd-inhibit --list --mode=block` does show one item.

```
jjoseph 1000 jjoseph 56388 gsd-media-keys handle-power-key:handle-suspend-key:handle-hibernate-key GNOME handling keypresses block

1 inhibitors listed.
```

Comment: The same block listed on my other machine as well but it sleeps after 15 minutes.

Comment: Hi, did you ever find a solution for this?